# Plot not showing in Shiny R application

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny

I have a Shiny app.

Part of my data-frame attached:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nvg3cj6u37l2rc8/example.csv?dl=0

I have code:

**Ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(D3TableFilter)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyUI(navbarPage("App",


                   tabPanel("Compare",
                            fluidRow(
                              column(4, selectInput("statesearch", "Region: ",
                                                    c('region1', 'region2', 'region3', 'region4', 'region5',  'region6', 'region7', 'region8', 'region9', 'region10', 'region11', 'region12'),
                                                    selected="All"),

                                     br()
                              ),

                              column(8,
                                     plotOutput("g2", width = "100%"))
                            )

                   )


)
)
```

and **Server.R**

```
require(ggplot2)
require(shiny)



# Load the dataset

loadData <- function() {

  comp <- read.csv("./data/comp.csv")
  return(df)
}




# Plot comparision
getCompare<- function(df, reaction){
  comp <- df[[4]]
  state = reaction$state
  indices <- which(comp$State == state)
  new_df <- df[indices, ]
  g2 <- ggplot(new_df, aes(x=Year, y= Percent, fill= Name)) +
    geom_bar(aes(width=.65), stat="identity")
  return(g2)
}

##### GLOBAL OBJECTS #####

# Shared data
globalData <- loadData()

##### SHINY SERVER #####
# Create shiny server.
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  cat("Press \"ESC\" to exit...\n")
  # Copy the data frame 
  localFrame <- globalData


  getReaction3 <- reactive({
    return(list(
      state = input$statesearch
    ))
  }) # getReaction3


  # Output Plots.

  output$g2 <- renderPlot({print(getGraph(localFrame, getReaction3()))},width=1000,height=600) # output map
}) # shinyServer
```

I am experiencing problem with plot showing when I run code.

I get:

> Warning in is.na(e2) :   is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of
>   type 'NULL' Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) :
>   incorrect length (0), expecting: 547565

If I substitute   `filter(State == "region1")` and run step by step code in a different script everything is plotted fine.
Can you please help
Regards

Comment: A small code snippet where you can reproduce this error would be of help

Comment: Please check the edited version

Comment: Thank you. One more thing, can you create some mock-up data for the file ./data/comp.csv?

Comment: They are attached in the dropbox link I provided

Comment: still the dropbox link didn't work for me.  Could you post it on a gist on github?